# Input event doesn't work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I am using jQuery and I need to filter some data. On every browser my code works as I expect. However on mobile devices it hides everything and doesn't work.

What i am doing wrong? Thank you for your help :)

```
<form id="region-filter" method="post">
    <label>
        <span>Nach Region suchen:</span>
        <input type="text">
    </label>
</form>
<div class="gridWrapper">
    <?php
        $regions = rest_api_call('regions.json');
    ?>
    <?php foreach($regions['message']['data'] as $region) : ?>
        <?php //var_dump($region); ?>
        <div class="grid grid-ms-1-2 grid-md-1-3 grid-xl-1-4">
            <div class="region" data-id="<?php echo $region['id']; ?>">
                <div class="check"></div>
                <div class="city-wrapper" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $region['icon']['svg']; ?>');">
                    <div class="city-name">
                        <?php echo $region['name']; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

```js
$('#region-filter input').on({
  input: function() {
    let val = $(this).val();
    $('.regions .gridWrapper .grid').each(function() {
      let name = $(this).find('.city-name').text();
      let match = name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val);
      if (match !== -1) {
        $(this).show();
      } else {
        $(this).hide();
      }
    });
  },
  keypress: function(e) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: If everything gets hidden then the `input` event must be working for the logic to flow to the `hide()` call. In that case the issue would be with the `indexOf(val)` result. Can you please add your HTML to the question.

Comment: I added html. But I think when everythink works on desktop it should be problem in javascript or in mobile devices or?